# How to install epson l220 printer and scanner driver in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my HP laptop. Now want to print pdf with my Epson printer L220. I have tried all the procedure on the page that goes to the epson page and download driver for the printer and install it. But failed. The computer can find my printer but while I want to print a pdf, the printer prints a blank page. Now how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please clarifiy 'failed', what went wrong ? If your computer able to print (although it's a blank page) successfully, so what 'failed' then? Please [edit] your post

Comment: Go to settings -> Devices -> Printers. Do you  find the printer `Epson L220` there?

Comment: @Emmet The pdf page I intend to print is full of content, but when print, it just bypass the paper , without any content on the paper

Comment: @Marmayogi Yes, it shows Epson L220, but while I print any pdf content , it cannot print the content , simply bypass the paper. this problem arise in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Can you please check the output of `sudo lpstat -s` and `sudo lpstat -t` commands?

Comment: Does your epson L220 printer print non-pdf content? have you tried with printing simple  text files?

Comment: @Marmayogi outputs are as follows ----- no system default destination
device for L220: usb://EPSON/L220%20Series?serial=5647584B3233333274&interface=1

Comment: @Marmayogi scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for L220: usb://EPSON/L220%20Series?serial=5647584B3233333274&interface=1
L220 accepting requests since Thursday 28 March 2019 02:08:56 PM IST
printer L220 is idle.  enabled since Thursday 28 March 2019 02:08:56 PM IST

Comment: @Marmayogi Yes I tried with simple word document, but this time also no printing occurs , printer simply by-pass the page

Comment: Please try with simple text file. Use Notepad. The file extension should be ".txt". The idea is we are making sure that your printer prints nothing.

Comment: It seems that output of lpstat command says that "scheduler is running no system default destination device for L220" which means we should set `System's Default Printer Destination`.

Comment: Check the system's default printer by this command `lpstat -d`. Now you name it as `luna`. Issue command `sudo lpadmin -d luna` and then issue `lpstat -d`. The output should be `system default destination: luna`. Now you try to print some document and see you taste success!

Comment: Done all the things you say at last , but still it prompts "no system default destination"

Comment: Please issue the following two commands: 1) `echo 'export LPDEST=luna' | tee -a ~/.bashrc` 2. `echo 'export PRINTER=luna' | tee -a ~/.bashrc`. Reboot the system. Now type command `pstat -d` and see output to be `default destination: luna`. You try to print any document and see printer is working. If the  problem persists, @Bapi Saha, let us go into a chat session.

Comment: @Marmayogi alos do the last all the things you told , but still the problem is same. Output is as follows "Command 'pstat' not found, but there are 19 similar ones.
"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91675/discussion-between-marmayogi-and-bapi-saha).

Comment: My mistake. It should be `lpstat -d ` and see output to be `default destination: luna`. Please try to print @Bapi Saha.